# Is it good practice to use lambda expressions instead of foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, lambda

Today I was working on a TextToSpeech app and I've came across a situation where I need to check if the selected voice by the user is installed on the computer.

For this, I could either use a **foreach**:

```
bool foundVoice = false;
foreach (var v in installedVoices)
{
    if (v.VoiceInfo.Name.Contains(selectedVoice) && v.VoiceInfo.Culture.ToString() == selectedCulture)
    {
        foundVoice = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or a **lamda expression**:

```
var foundVoice = installedVoices.FirstOrDefault(v => v.VoiceInfo.Name.Contains(selectedVoice) && v.VoiceInfo.Culture.ToString() == selectedCulture);
```

The installedVoices is a **ReadOnlyCollection< InstalledVoice >** from **SpeechSynthesizer**.

Definitely, the lambda expression looks more cleaner than the foreach but which one is better practice?

From what I have tested the foreach seems to be **slightly** faster than the lambda expression.

Also, both foreach and lambda can be extended in the future if there is need for immediate action on the InstalledVoice.

Comment: The only way I can tell that the first snippet searches for the first occurence of something, is by seeing the *second* snippet. Which should answer the question.

Comment: It's a matter of preference. And code consistency. And team consensus. There are a bunch of parameters which decide which is "better". Readability? Performance?

Comment: If you want a bool, you could do: `var foundVoice = installedVoices.Any(v => v.VoiceInfo.Name.Contains(selectedVoice) && v.VoiceInfo.Culture.ToString() == selectedCulture);` This would be the true equivalent to your foreach.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters. The more you (and your team) are familiar with Linq and Linq-like thinking, the more you will prefer the lambda style. However, "old school" people are used in thinking in foreach patterns and will recognize those. Btw, the two snippets are not equivalent: the first returns true/false while the second returns the voice or null. To have a fair comparison they should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I like the cleanliness of lambdas, but what about breakpoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the lambda expression looks more cleaner than the foreach but which one is better practice?

"Looks cleaner" is a perfect indicator of a better practice. It is extremely rare for performance to change in a meaningful way depending on the language facility in use, so readability is the most important measure of how good a particular construct is for your code. Readability is what ultimately decides the maintainability of your code, even when the only reader of your code is you.

Note that this is a case-by-case decision, because lambdas may be better in one situation and loops could be better in another situation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's good practice to use LINQ in this case, because it's more readable. However, to me `installedVoices.Any` instead of `installedVoices.FirstOrDefault` would be even more readable.

Comment: Also, `.Any` is the logical equivalent to his foreach.

Comment: What will installedVoice.Any return if there are more than one voice that satisfies the condition?

Comment: @CatalinHoha It will return true.

Comment: Oh, yes! Now I saw that it returns a bool. I will use .Any in that case because it is more suitable for what I need.